# str assignment in a matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

Unable to modify individual elements in str format in a two dimensional matrix. The initial matrix elements are initialised as "_". Some elements are to be modifed to "X".
Here is the part of the code

```
board=[]  
for i in range(3):  
        board+=['_'*3]  
        board[i]=" ".join(board[i])  
        print(board[i])  
def game_board(board):  
    for i in range(3):  
        board[i]="".join(board[i])  
        print(board[i])  
j=0  
while(j<=8):  
    while(j%2==0):  
        print("First player's turn")  
        row=int(input("Row="))  
        col=int(input("Column="))  
        while(board[int(col)-1][2*int(row)-2]!='_'):  
            print("Wrong Input")  
            row=int(input("Row="))  
            col=int(input("Column="))  
        else:  
            board[int(col)-1][2*(int(row)-1)]='X'  
            print(game_board(board))  
            print(board)  
            j+=1  
    else:  
        print("Second player's turn")  
        row=int(input("Row="))  
        col=int(input("Column="))  
        while(board[int(col)-1][2*int(row)-2]!="_"):  
            print("Wrong Input")  
            row=int(input("Row="))  
            col=int(input("Column="))  
        else:  
            board[int(col)-1][2*int(row)-2]=="O"  
            print(game_board(board))  
            j+=1
```

Please suggest a way to modify individual matrix string elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just leave your board as lists of lists right until you're ready to print it:

```
def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print ' '.join(row)

def game_board(width, height):
    return [['_' for i in xrange(width)] for j in xrange(height)]

board = game_board(3,3)

board[0][2] = 'X'
board[1][1] = 'X'

print_board( board )
```